# Easier way to create implicitly shared classes with C++11?

Tags: c++, qt

Here is minimal example of Qt-like implicitly shared/COW class:

```
#include <QSharedData>
#include <QString>

class EmployeeData : public QSharedData
{
public:
    EmployeeData() : id(-1) { }
    EmployeeData(const EmployeeData &other)
        : QSharedData(other), id(other.id), name(other.name) { }
    ~EmployeeData() { }

    int id;
    QString name;
};

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee() { d = new EmployeeData; }
    Employee(int id, QString name) {
        d = new EmployeeData;
        setId(id);
        setName(name);
    }
    Employee(const Employee &other)
          : d (other.d)
    {
    }
    void setId(int id) { d->id = id; }
    void setName(QString name) { d->name = name; }

    int id() const { return d->id; }
    QString name() const { return d->name; }

private:
    QSharedDataPointer<EmployeeData> d;
};
```

[Link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshareddatapointer.html#details)

Is there a way to get rid of such basic getter/setter methods, to write as less code as posible?

I want to write something like in Rust, which is very similar to Qt's implicitly shared classes (ref counting and stuff).

For example:

```
struct A {
    ComplexStruct complexValue; // some struct which has lost of data
}

struct B {
    A value;
    int count;
}

int main() {
    B b;
    A a = b.value; // here I get deep copy of struct A with ComplexStruct, which is slow,
    // but with Qt-like implicitly sharing it will be fast and easy
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "get rid of such basic getter/setter methods" That has nothing to do with Qt's implicit sharing, it's just basic API design.  If you really wanted to, you could just wrap Qt's implicit sharing mechanism around a `ComplexStruct` instance and expose the whole struct in one getter/setter pair.